# Is it possible to run a SQL query with EntityFramework that joins three tables between two databases?

Tags: entity-framework

So I've got a SQL query that is called from an API that I'm trying to write an integration test for.  I have the method that prepares the data totally working, but I realized that I don't know how to actually execute the query to check that data (and run the test).  Here is what the query looks like (slightly redacted to protect confidental data):

```
SELECT HeaderQuery.[headerid], 
       kaq.[applicationname], 
       HeaderQuery.[usersession], 
       HeaderQuery.[username], 
       HeaderQuery.[referringurl], 
       HeaderQuery.[route], 
       HeaderQuery.[method], 
       HeaderQuery.[logdate], 
       HeaderQuery.[logtype], 
       HeaderQuery.[statuscode], 
       HeaderQuery.[statusdescription], 
       DetailQuery.[detailid], 
       DetailQuery.[name], 
       DetailQuery.[value] 
FROM   [DATABASE1].[dbo].[apilogheader] HeaderQuery 
       LEFT JOIN [DATABASE1].[dbo].[apilogdetails] DetailQuery 
              ON HeaderQuery.[headerid] = DetailQuery.[headerid] 
       INNER JOIN [DATABASE2].[dbo].[apps] kaq 
               ON HeaderQuery.[applicationid] = kaq.[applicationid] 
WHERE  HeaderQuery.[applicationid] = @applicationid1 
       AND HeaderQuery.[logdate] >= @logdate2 
       AND HeaderQuery.[logdate] <= @logdate3
```

For the sake of the test, and considering I already have the SQL script, I was hoping to be able to just execute that script above (providing the where clause programmatically) using `context.Database.SqlQuery<string>(QUERY)` but since I have two different contexts, I'm not sure how to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is no, EF doesn’t support cross database queries. However there are a few things you can try.

- You can use two different database contexts (one for each database).
  Run your respective queries and then merge / massage the data after
  the query returns.
- Create a database view and query the view through EF.
- Using a SYNONYM
  https://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2011/05/22/tricking-ef-to-span-multiple-databases/
- If the databases are on the same server, you can try using a
  DbCommandInterceptor

I’ve had this requirement before and personally like the view option.

Comment: Thanks for the response!  I realized that I actually didn't even need to execute the query.  Since it was an integration test, I actually needed to call the endpoint, but I figured I'd leave this question up to see if it was possible.